# Redirect to different location based on presence/absence of a parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way to differentiate a Redirect on the basis of whether it has parameters or doesn't?

Example:
I want to redirect everything targetted at
http://www.example.com/news.php?id=123
to
http://www.example.com/old-news.php?id=123
but if no parameter is given, it should redirect to 
news-overview.php, same path.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in order to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ /old-news\.php [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ /news-overview\.php [L,R]
```

note that the query string automatically gets appended to the redirected URL. You can change the `R` to `R=301` if you want to permanent redirect.